# Catchment tank Grundfos jet pump won't shut off

Tags: plumbing

I have a catchment tank with grundfos jet pump and pressure tank. The tank comes up to 60 psi, the pump pressure switch arcs back and forth. I have adjusted the pressure switch to no affect. I have replaced the foot valve and the pick up line.

Comment: Could the pressure tank be water logged?  No air buffer in the tank or bladder is busted/leaking.

Comment: There was 22#pressure and increased it to 38# pressure. No water on the ground.

Comment: A water logged tank will not leak water.  It will be filled to the top of the tank with water without the pressure buffer, air gives to it.  Usually the pressure gauge will go up and down fast, instead of having the pressure slowly bleed off.

Comment: with the pressure tank at 60# and the pump unplugged the bleeder screw on pressure sensor line on the top of pump doesn't show pressure when it is unscrewed

Comment: I sounds like your pressure tank is water-logged.   As a diagnostic, turn off the pump,open a cold water valve, if water-logged the pressure should drop very quickly. If so, you can add air to the tank with a compressor WHILE THE COLD FAUCET IS OPEN. Usually tanks have a Schrader  type valve to recharge it. A few minutes of putting compressed air in the tank should drive out enough water for a decent buffer.  Then close the cold water faucet and USING A GAUGE, pressurize the tank to about 25-30 .  PSI   If the pump starts cycling normally, you found the problem....Continued below...

Comment: Pressure tanks with internal bladders do fail, which results in air getting absorbed by the water ending up water-logging the tank.   If you have a really old school pressure tank w/o a  bladder, it's a regular task to drain out some water and re-pressurize with air.

Comment: So, with the pressure up to 60, turn off the pump breaker since the pressure switch is evidently not switching off right. With no water use or the valve away from the tank to the rest of the house closed, does pressure hold? Put a bucket under the drain that should be on the tank tee (or a short hose into a bucket) and record how much water comes out until the pressure is down to 40. If it's not several gallons, your tank is probably bad. You can use a chart for your make and model of tank to know exactly how many gallons you should get between those pressures.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to replace the pressure switch.

Depending on your detailed symptoms you may *also* need a new pressure tank, but when you say the pressure switch "arcs back and forth" I'm going to jump on the pressure switch until you provide better details about the possible symptoms indicting the pressure tank. You don't describe the pressure instantly dropping to 40 and then instantly back up to 60, which is what I'd expect to see with a failed tank and a good switch.